# what does "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath()))" do if there are more than one element with the same xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Imagine that I use:

```
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath()));
```

to fetch a web element, but what if there are more than one element with the same xpath but just one of them is supposed to be clickable(visible)? will it bring me that exact web element? or will it throw an exception because of the ones that are not visible?

Comment: Seems like this is something you can test and find out how it works very easily for yourself. Create an XPath for `A` tags and click on `we`... what happens? You will learn a lot more if you spend some time investigating things on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [implementation of `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java) you'll see that it gets its element through `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`. In turn this function uses a `findElement` function to get its element, which in turn calls `WebDriver.findElement`. The [the documentation for `WebDriver.findElement`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) states that it returns the first element that matches the selector.

Therefore, even if you have multiple elements that match what you pass to `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` only the first element will be considered by the test. If the first element can be clicked, then the condition will be met. If the first element cannot be clicked, then the wait will timeout. It does not matter if the other matching elements can be clicked or not. You should adjust your selector to select only the element that interests you.

Comment: **your answers are always very explanatory and complete, thanks a lot**